# How to use Replace method in xlwings

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, xlwings

I'm working on data collection using python and xlwings.
Then I'd like to replace some formula to another one, but I can't find correct method or tips for it.
I know that I can combine VBA and python, it would be more simple, however it's more desirable use only python because of simplicity and efficiency.

Problem;
I'm trying to edit xlsb file, but openpyxl doesn't support xlsb, so I'd like to resolve that problem using xlwings.
Ex. replace "AAA" -> "BBB"

If you know some methods to replace the formula in the sheet of Excel(xlsb) using python, it would be appreciated if you teach me how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: add some code sample

Comment: it would probably good to add corresponding tags, like python.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sheet.range("A1:A9").api.Replace("AAA", "BBB")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xlwings.sheets[x].cells.options(searchformula=True, replaceformula=True).api.replace('AAA', 'BBB')
```

I tried hundreds of times to figure out the searchformula/replaceformula staff LoL, couldn't find an answer anywhere.